Virtual network peering and service endpoints - how to allow two Azure app services to communicate
I need some help in setting up some Azure infrastructure in Terraform.
I have app service A which is in vnetA in subnetA, and app service B in vnetB and subnetB.
AppA, vnetA, and subnetA were created manually a long time ago, and B resources I have created myself in Terraform.
I have added a virtual network peering between the two vnets, but when calling appB from appA I still get 403.
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnetB" {
  name                 = "subnetB"
  resource_group_name  = "rgB"
  virtual_network_name = "vnetB"
  address_prefixes     = [cidrsubnet(azurerm_virtual_network.vnetB.address_space[0], 2, 1)]

  delegation {
    name = "appServiceDelegation"
    service_delegation {
        name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
        actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }  

  service_endpoints =  ["Microsoft.Web"]
}

What am I missing?
I have gone through similar questions, in subnetB I have added both app service delegation and service endpoints as was advised (here) but this did not fix the issue.
Update: I have verified that the address spaces of these vnets do not overlap (as this is one of the possible reasons for the failure to establish vnet peering).

You're correct, ensuring that the address spaces of the two Virtual Networks (VNets) do not overlap is indeed a critical requirement for establishing VNet peering in Azure successfully It works as expected for me when we make sure the address IP doesn't overlap @sobrod

After a lot of tweaking of my Terraform code for service B (thank you Vinay B) I have found the reason I was getting 403.
When I went to the Networking section of function B and looked into Inbound traffic configuration, in the list of Site access and rules, I saw this warning

and when hovering over the warning sign, I was getting this: 
So, it turns out that the subnet A (which I didn't manage via Terraform) did not have Microsoft.Web endpoint set up.
When I added the endpoint manually, I finally started getting 200 responses.
